# Why declarative pipelines need to run on master if there are build executors available?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using recent Jenkins version 2.286 and since this update there is an security hint: "You should set up distributed builds. Building on the controller node can be a security issue. See [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Security+implication+of+building+on+master)."

But I'm already doing so with three Jenkins nodes and I also fully understand the security implications.

The problem here is, that there are two jobs that need to run an the master, since they are the jobs that deploy those Jenkins nodes. That means I can not reduce the build executors to 0.

I've also tried using the [Job Restrictions plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-restrictions/) to restrict which jobs can run on the master. This problem here is that all my jobs are waiting for the master queue do have a free slot available. I wonder why, because they all are declarative pipelines and define something like:

```
agent {
  label 'some-different-node-label'
}
```

Which means they aren't really executed on the master node.

Questions here are:

- Is this intentionally that all jobs require the master node before switching the agent?
- Is there any configuration option to change that?
- Is there a way to execute the deploy jobs on master, even if there aren't any executed defined (to bypass that behavior)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With declarative pipelines the lightweight code checkout is done on the Master node to get a Jenkinsfile for that job.  While this doesnt use an executor on the Master perhaps the Job Restriction Plugin is still blocking this (I havent used it before so cannot comment)

Also certain pipeline actions are delegated back to the Master node as well (e.g. the `withAWSParameterStore` step.

If you look at the console output for a Declarative pipeline job, you will see lots of output (mainly around library checkouts or git checkouts) before you see the start of the pipeline `[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline`.  All that is done on the Master.

Unfortunately this cannot be changed as the Master needs to do this work to find out which agent type to delegate the job to.

Depending on how you are running you agents, you could use something like the EC2 Cloud Plugin to generate you agent nodes which wouldn't require a job to do it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately those Nodes are deployed on bare metal with Docker. Guess I'll open an issue at Jenkins then for this problem.